# How many subgroups of order $n$ does $D_n$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

How many subgroups of order $n$ does $D_n$ have?

My work:

Since subgroups of $D_n$ are either cyclic or dihedral, the subgroups of order $n$ of $D_n$ are $\left< r \right>$ (cyclic) and $D_{n/2}$ (dihedral). However, this works only for $n$ is even and $n\geq 2$. I don't know how to do when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Note that any subgroup of order $n$ is normal. I think it will be easier to see from this angle (and you are correct in the even case)

Comment: @TokenToucan I haven't learnt anything about normal groups. This question is listed as "question to ponder" in the cyclic group chapter. I wonder in the case when n is odd, if there is only one such subgroup $<r>$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All subgroups and all normal subgroups are classified in K. Conrad's text on [Dihedral Groups II](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf), Theorem $3.1$ and $3.8$.

Section $3$ gives *all* subgroups of $D_n$, for $n$ odd and $n$ even. In particular,
Theorem $3.1$ gives a complete listing of all subgroups, namely all 
$⟨r^d⟩$ with $d|n$, and all $⟨r^d,r^is⟩$, where $d|n$ and $0≤i≤d−1$.