# Subgroups of index 2 of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product

I know that the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times S_3$ has $3$ subgroups of index $2$ (i.e. of $6$ elements). It is easy to see that $2$ of them are $\{0\} \times S_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times A_3$, but I am struggling to find the third one, that probably isn't a direct product of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and a subgroup of $S_3$ like the first $2$. What can I do?

Comment: Each of them comes from a character $G\to \pm 1$, the product of the two gives a 3rd character/normal subgroup of index 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third subgroup is a "diagonal". It consists of all elements of the form
$$
\{(\operatorname{sgn}\sigma, \sigma)\mid \sigma\in\Bbb S_3\}
$$
Each of these subgroups appear as the kernel of a surjective homomorphism onto $\Bbb Z_2$ (index 2 subgroups always do). This probably would've helped you find the final subgroup.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* We know that $\Bbb Z/2\times S_3\cong D_6$, and we know *all* subgroups of dihedral groups. Then we just pick out the ones of order $6$.

See for example [How many subgroups of order $n$ does $D_n$ have?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685756/how-many-subgroups-of-order-n-does-d-n-have)